# Incorrect sum - For loop in C

Tags: c, for-loop

I am trying to sum values in a for loop with C. The initial value of variable `x = 1` and I want to double it a set number of times and add the result. I have made the for loop, but my sum is always off by the initial value.

For example, if `x = 1`, the pattern should go:

```
1, 2, 4, 8, 16
```

...and the `total` should be `31`. Unfortunately, `total` is off by one.

```
int x = 1;
int y = 10;
int total;

for(int i = 1; i < y; i++)
{   
   x *= 2;
   total += x;
}

printf("Total: %d\n", total);
```

This is off by one. How can I have the loop start with `1` instead of `2`?

Comment: Thats because the first value x=1 is never added to the total. When it first reaches `total += x` the value of x is already 2.

Comment: I would remove the for loop and write `total = (2<<y)-1;` or similar (since your code is buggy as-is, it's hard to tell exactly what output you wanted).

Comment: Is this homework? If so, please tag it as such so we know how to respond.

Comment: Why is your `total` not initialized? With garbage as initial value of `total`, I'm surprised that you are only "off by one".

Comment: @R.. Probably you mean `(1<<y)-1` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Switch the two statements in the body of the for loop.  Also it is a good idea to initialize total to 0, in case you want to move all of this into a function.

Comment: I'd say it is a good idea to initialize `total` to 0 regardless of whether the OP want to move it into a function.

Comment: You're right @Andrey +1.  Even though global ints are initialized to zero, it is bad practice to rely on this.  It is harder to read without, and the initialization actually isn't common knowledge.

Comment: Yes, but I don't see any indication of `total` being global. Moreover, as I noted in my answer, I believe the OP's intent was different and the proper value to initialize `total` with is actually `1`, not `0`. (I.e. there was no need to change the cycle). If I'm right, the I'm afraid the OP followed your approach without really understanding why the original one didn't work.

Comment: Granted.  It's always hard to tell when you see a code snippet.  I was trying to get the _closest_ to what the OP was asking, even though starting the sum at 1 is fine, as is 2<sup>y</sup>-1 or `(1<<y)-1`

Answer (score 0):

As is usually the case with erroneous code, there is more that one way to "fix" it. While you made it sufficiently clear as to *what* you are trying to implement, nobody knows *how* you are trying to implement it.

- As @Ray Toal already noted in his answer, the correct result can be obtained by initializing `total` to `0` before the cycle and doing `x *= 2` *after* the addition inside the cycle.
- Alternatively, one can say that the cycle is OK as it is in the original code. You just have to initialize the `total` to `1` before the cycle.

Which approach is closer to what you were trying to implement originally - only you know. In both cases make sure you make the correct number of iterations.